# How to make a countdown timer repeat

Tags: java, android, timer, countdowntimer

It is my first time working with Android Studio and my Java skills are basically non-existent so I need a little help with a project I am working on. 
      I need to make a timer that repeats after a certain break. The user should decide how many times should timer repeat and what is the duration of break.
      So far I did the standard countdown timer but no matter what i try i can't make it repeat

That is the working code I have so far
 Interface:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.asus.timer.MainActivity"
android:padding="20dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
>


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextSession"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:hint="Session (seconds)"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextBreak"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:hint="Break (seconds)"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextRepeats"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:hint="Repeats"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonStart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start!"
    android:padding="20dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewTimer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="60dp"
    android:paddingTop="40dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
```

Functionality

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText editTextSession;
EditText editTextBreak;
EditText editTextRepeats;
Button buttonStart;
TextView textViewTimer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editTextSession =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSession);
    editTextBreak =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextBreak);
    editTextRepeats =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextRepeats);
    buttonStart =(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
    textViewTimer =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTimer);

    buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String text = editTextSession.getText().toString();
            int seconds = Integer.valueOf(editTextSession.getText().toString());
            CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(seconds * 1000, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millis) {
                    textViewTimer.setText("time:" + (int) (millis / 1000));
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    extViewTimer.setText("Finished!");
                }
            }.start();
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're looking for another way to create timer, you can do something like this with `Runnable()` :

```
private TextView timeCounterTextView;
private int smsTimeOut = 10; // 10 SECONDS
private Runnable timeCounterRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        if (smsTimeOut == 1) {
            //Do whatever when timeout
        }
        smsTimeOut--;
        timeCounterTextView.setText(String.valueOf(smsTimeOut));
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};
```

and whenever you want to start countdown initialize and start timer with `init()` method like below :

```
private void init(){
    handler.removeCallbacks(timeCounterRunnable);
    smsTimeOut = 10;
    handler = new Handler();
    handler.post(timeCounterRunnable);
}
```

anytime you want to repeat you can call `init()` again.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Did You try Integer.parseInt(String value) instead of Integer.valueOf(String value)? Maybe it will make a diffrence. You can add an exception if someone type wrong value.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
timer.start();
```

And stop it with:

```
timer.cancel();
```

Example:

```
String text = editTextSession.getText().toString();
int seconds = Integer.valueOf(text);

//get how many repeat
String repeatText = editTextSession.getText().toString();
int repeat = Integer.valueOf(repeatText);

int count= 0;

CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(seconds * 1000, 1000) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millis) {
        textViewTimer.setText("time:" + (int)(millis / 1000));
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        extViewTimer.setText("Finished!");
        count++;
        //check if count still less than repeat number
        if(count < repeat){
             Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                     public void run() {
                        countDownTimer.start();
                     }};

             new Handler().postDelayed(r,2000); //delay repeat timer 2 seconds 

        }
        else{
             countDownTimer.cancel();
             count = 0;
        }
    }
}.start();
```

Comment: ZeroOne, do  you have a suggestion how to add an interval between the repeats ?

Comment: you want to delay the repeat process is it?